# Sort array of arrays by index

Tags: json, sorting, lodash

I have the following multidimensional array:

```
const users = [
  [
    1020,
    "10-FEB-2019",
    "ajd",
    "Mary",
    "jones",
    "a@gmail.com",
    "25 main Lane",
    "brooklyn",
    "NY",
    "11210",
    "5165551212",
    "MEMB",
    "alk",
    "14-FEB-2019",
    93.35
  ],
  [
    1010,
    "08-FEB-2019",
    "dak",
    "Daisy",
    "smith",
    "d@gmail.com",
    "62 stone Drive",
    "brooklyn",
    "NY",
    "11210",
    "5165551212",
    "ADMIN",
    "ERR",
    "19-MAR-2019",
    71.487
  ],
  [
    1000,
    "05-FEB-2019",
    "alk",
    "Arnold",
    "smith",
    "a@gmail.com",
    "62 stone Drive",
    "brooklyn",
    "NY",
    "11210",
    "5165551212",
    "ADMIN",
    "alk",
    "14-FEB-2019",
    203.41
  ]
]
```

I want to sort this array by last name (index 4) - jones, smith, smith.
I tried this `var sorted = _.sortBy(users[4]);` but it didn't work.

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `_.sortBy()` or `_.orderBy()` with the index of the "column" you want to sort by:

```js
const users = [[1020,"10-FEB-2019","ajd","Mary","jones","a@gmail.com","25 main Lane","brooklyn","NY","11210","5165551212","MEMB","alk","14-FEB-2019",93.35],[1010,"08-FEB-2019","dak","Daisy","smith","d@gmail.com","62 stone Drive","brooklyn","NY","11210","5165551212","ADMIN","ERR","19-MAR-2019",71.487],[1000,"05-FEB-2019","alk","Arnold","smith","a@gmail.com","62 stone Drive","brooklyn","NY","11210","5165551212","ADMIN","alk","14-FEB-2019",203.41]]

const result = _.sortBy(users, 4)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```